# import theano results in ImportError

Tags: python-2.7, cuda, nvidia, theano, pylearn

I'm trying to use theano but I get an error when I import it.
I've installed cuda_6.5.14_linux_64.run, and passed all the recommended test in Chapter 6 of [this](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf) NVIDIA PDF.
Ultimately I want to be able to install pylearn2, but I get the exact same error as below when I try to compile it.

EDIT1: My theanorc looks like:

```
[cuda]

root = /usr/local/cuda-6.5


[global]
device = gpu
floatX=float32
```

If I replace gpu with cpu, the command import theano succeeds.

```
Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 1.9.0 (64-bit)| (default, Aug 21 2014, 18:22:21) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org

Imported NumPy 1.9.1, SciPy 0.14.0, Matplotlib 1.3.1
Type "scientific" for more details.
>>> import theano
Using gpu device 0: GeForce GTX 750 Ti
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 92, in <module>
    theano.sandbox.cuda.tests.test_driver.test_nvidia_driver1()
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/tests/test_driver.py", line 28, in test_nvidia_driver1
    profile=False)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function.py", line 223, in function
    profile=profile)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 512, in pfunc
    on_unused_input=on_unused_input)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1312, in orig_function
    defaults)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 1181, in create
    _fn, _i, _o = self.linker.make_thunk(input_storage=input_storage_lists)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/link.py", line 434, in make_thunk
    output_storage=output_storage)[:3]
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/vm.py", line 847, in make_all
    no_recycling))
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/__init__.py", line 237, in make_thunk
    compute_map, no_recycling)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 606, in make_thunk
    output_storage=node_output_storage)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 948, in make_thunk
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 891, in __compile__
    keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1322, in cthunk_factory
    key=key, fn=self.compile_cmodule_by_step, keep_lock=keep_lock)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 996, in module_from_key
    module = next(compile_steps)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 1237, in compile_cmodule_by_step
    preargs=preargs)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/sandbox/cuda/nvcc_compiler.py", line 444, in compile_str
    return dlimport(lib_filename)
  File "/home/g/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.py", line 284, in dlimport
    rval = __import__(module_name, {}, {}, [module_name])
ImportError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', GpuCAReduce{add}{1}(<CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector)>), '\n', '/home/g/.theano/compiledir_Linux-3.11.0-26-generic-x86_64-with-debian-wheezy-sid-x86_64-2.7.8-64/tmpWYqQw5/7173b40d34b57da0645a57198c96dbcc.so: undefined symbol: __fatbinwrap_66_tmpxft_00004bf1_00000000_12_cuda_device_runtime_compute_50_cpp1_ii_5f6993ef', '[GpuCAReduce{add}{1}(<CudaNdarrayType(float32, vector)>)]')
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered exactly the same question.

My solution is to replace cuda-6.5 with cuda-5.5, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

We also saw this error.  We found that putting /usr/local/cuda-6.5/bin in $PATH seemed to fix it (even with the root = ... line in .theanorc).